# How to remove Server header?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-10

In my ASP.Net Core 3.1 application I want to remove the Server header from the response headers, I tried the below things in the web config

`<requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true">`

`<remove name="Server" />`

either option didn't work. normally when I see the response headers in the browser, the Server header does not see but when I use Nmap there I can see this "_http-server-header: Microsoft-IIS/10.0"

I am not getting where exactly this needs to be configured.

Many thanks

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/everything-you-might-need-about-iis-server-header-58ca268547be

Answer (score 2):

You could try to modify the UseKestrel setting in Program.CS:

```
   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseKestrel(option => option.AddServerHeader = false);
                
            });
```

Comment: To those that downgraded the answer - it would be good if you provided a reason!

Comment: this absolutely does the job. maybe it had been downvoted because it seems to apply to .NET core 5...

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to remove the Server header from the response.

1.Using URLRewrite

- Open the site on which you would like to remove the Server header and
  click on the URLRewrite section.
- Click on the "View Server Variables" in the Actions pane in the right
  hand side.
- Click on the Add button and then enter "RESPONSE_SERVER" in the
  textbox provided.
- Now we need to create an outbound rule as follow:

  ```
  <outboundRules>
   <rule name="Remove server">
       <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SERVER" pattern=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" />
   </rule>
  </outboundRules>
  ```

2.Using the Registry key.

Create a DWORD entry called DisableServerHeader in the following Registry key and set the value to 1.

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters
```

After adding the Registry key, restart the HTTP service using the net stop http command and the net start http command. If the HTTP service doesn’t start up then use the iisreset command. If that also doesn’t work then you can restart the server.

3.Using the URLScan tool.

Open the URLScan.ini file typically located in the %WINDIR%\System32\Inetsrv\URLscan folder. After opening it, search for the key RemoveServerHeader . By default it is set to 0, but to remove the Server header, change the value to 1.

Comment: I tried the first option, it effects on response header of the browser but when I scan the site thru nmap I still see the MS httpd IIS 10.0 server version.
The 2nd and 3rd option I cannot try because the site is hosted on Azure as an app service

Comment: This can only be used by the client to "hide" the ServerHeader, not a real deletion.

Comment: Yes, Do you know any other way?

Comment: As far as I know, there are only three methods.